# Any space $X$ can be embedded as a dense subset of a Lindelöf space.

Tags: general-topology

I have the following statement to prove, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

> Any space $X$ can be embedded as a dense subset of a Lindelöf space.

There is a hint associated to this exercise,

[*Hint:* Adjoin a point $p$ to $X$ whose nbhds are the sets $\{p\}\cup E$, where $E$ is a subset of $X$ whose complement in $X$ is Lindelöf.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint gives the game away, but there is one subtlety:

Define $Y = X \cup \{p\}$ as sets, where $p = \infty$ or any point not in $X$.
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the set of all **closed** subsets of $X$ that are Lindelöf (in the subspace topology).

Let $\mathcal{T}_Y$ be the topology with subbase $$\{\{p\} \cup E\mid X\setminus E \in \mathcal{L}\} \cup \mathcal{T}_X$$

and note that $i: X \to Y$ defined by $i(x)=x$ is an embedding and $Y$ is Lindelöf (taking any open cover, of $Y$ consider first what the open set containing $p$ is etc.; it's similar to the one-point compactification that way).

$X$ (rather, its topological copy $i[X]$) will only be dense in $Y$ if $X$ is not itself Lindelöf, but we can assume that WLOG anyway.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much.

Comment: @D.Math You're welcome. The original hint needs modifying, as I did, or else you'll add  open sets in $X$, and that would be bad.